# Intrinsic curvature circular reasoning?

Tags: metric-spaces, surfaces, curvature

Gauss remarkable theorem proves that the inhabitants of a 2D curved surface can discover that their surface is curved without being aware of the embedding dimension, simply calculating distances and angles.

However: in order to calculate distsnces and angles they must use the proper metric, expressed in their curvilinear coordinates. And in order to find this expression, they have to relate their curvilinear coordinates to the embedding euclidean space. So they need to "look outside".

Isn't it a circular reasoning? They must "look outside" to find the metric, which they then use to find the curvature intrinsically (???) Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The idea is that one may regard the surface $M$ with ametric $g$ as an abstract pair $(M,g)$. If we have an embedding $M\hookrightarrow \Bbb R^3$, we can use an unit normal vector field, etc, to compute the Gaussian curvature. The content of the theorem is that this does not depend on the embedding.

Comment: That's the danger of making colloquial versions of mathematical theorems: you can easily distort the meaning.

Comment: @ivo I am still confused: in practical terms, if the 2d inhabitants need to receive a metric from the outside, what is the utility of this theorem? They are still dependent from the outside. Who gives them the metric, if not the 3d inhabitants of the embedding space?

Answer (score 1):

This Is misleading in mathematics I agree. what they are saying that the curvature is invariant with respect to the embedding. this is like saying a tensor is invariant when you change coordinates. but this doesn't tell you what it is irrespective if coordinates, just that it doesn't matter what coordinates you use.

Measure Circle circumferences And radiuses intrinsically on a surface in the neighborhood of a point,  and if circumferences turn out to be 2 pi *r, than the surface is not curved at that point.